# Xml output not places where i want

Tags: plugins, php, xml

I have a script that checks status (daily with cron) of some sites and write result in a xml document. Xml is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xml>
  <sites>
   <site1>result of site1</site1>
   <site2>result of site2</site2>
   ...
  </sites>
 </xml>
```

Then i have a function that let me get xml content for each site with wordpress shortcodes , like this :

```
<?php
function CheckRemoteService($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'name' => 'txt',
 ), $atts));

$xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml');
echo $xml->sites->$name;

}
add_shortcode('checkmyurl','CheckRemoteService');
?>
```

Shortcodes give me the correct output but all results are placed on same row at top , like if are blocked there. I want to insert these results in a table with other data. Is this a xml limit or i have done some mistakes ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes must *return* content and not *echo* it.  See any of the examples in the codex for [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

So your callback function should probably be:

```
function CheckRemoteService($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'name' => 'txt',
 ), $atts));

$xml = simplexml_load_file('my.xml');
return $xml->sites->$name;

}
add_shortcode('checkmyurl','CheckRemoteService');
```